# Windows Service Application with Timer

Tags: c#, sql-server, timer, triggers, windows-services

I am new for Windows service and .net Programming

I created a windows application for the generating report using data from Microsoft MS SQL. Then I converted the windows application to windows service. And added the timer to it.

My actual requirement is, application should generate the report whenever sql table gets new record.

I converted to application to service and started properly. If there is no data in the table, runs the program immediately and comes to end.

How to make the timer to trigger the application whenever insert the new data in the sql table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really need to have a service? Why not keep the application as it is and run it at certain intervals using the Task Scheduler?

Comment: @ZippyV Sometimes i will get multiple inputs, we dont know exact time interval

Comment: In that case a timer on your service will be useless as well.

Comment: Thanks @ZippyV Is there any suggestion to do same task?

Comment: You are looking for a pub-sub solution. That is, your app has subscribed to some event from the MS SQL database. The database raises an event and your app gets notified. Your app then do whatever necessary. Whatever ZippyV suggested is a good solution. If that is hard to implement, you have to implement a polling solution. Your app requires a times that pulls the data from the MS SQL every minute. The other option is to schedule the app through the Windows Scheduler. The last two approaches run the app at an interval, so your app may or may not get data.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to run your code when the data in a table is changed, you might be interested in using a [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency(v=vs.110).aspx) object.

Code example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx